# Why does program freeze when using time.sleep()

Tags: python, opencv

So I am working on a OpenCV project which would detect if a certain hand sign has taken place. That part works.

I also wanted to make it so that it *waits* for a few seconds so it does not count accidental movements. But when I use `time.sleep()` or start time end time methods it either *freezes* my program and always executes the program and stops following the if conditions, or worse it simply doesn't execute the if statement ever.

Here is the code snippet I used. Btw I have already tried `time.sleep()` It would just freeze the program and always play the clip regardless of whether it followed my if statement or not.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```
import cv2
import time
import os
import HandTrackingModule as htm
from playsound import playsound

wCam, hCam = 1920, 1080
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)
frame = cap.read()
pTime = 0

detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=1)
Player1 = []
Player2 = []
while 1 > 0:

    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmlist = detector.findPosition(img, handNo=0, draw=False)

    if len(lmlist) != 0:
        Player1 = []
        Player2 = []
        
        if (lmlist[4][1] < lmlist[3][1] and lmlist[8][2] < lmlist[6][2] and lmlist[20][2] < lmlist[18][2] and lmlist[12][2] > lmlist[10][2] and lmlist[16][2] > lmlist[14][2]) == False:
        StartTime = time.time()
        
        if lmlist[4][1] < lmlist[3][1] and lmlist[8][2] < lmlist[6][2] and lmlist[20][2] < lmlist[18][2] and lmlist[12][2] > lmlist[10][2] and lmlist[16][2] > lmlist[14][2]:
        EndTime = time.time()

        Eyetime = EndTime - StartTime
        if Eyetime > 5:
            Player1.append("hello")
            playsound(r'C:\Users\haris\Documents\GitHub\Haz3-jolt\Pong_with_opencv\venv\notw.mp3')

        
    






    

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, f'FPS: {int(fps)}',(400,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I also have a bonus script Import called handtrackingmodule.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        #print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                            self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList
    
    def Marks(self,frame):
        myHands=[]
        frameRGB=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results=self.hands.process(frameRGB)
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks != None:
            for handLandMarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                myHand=[]
                for landMark in handLandMarks.landmark:
                    myHand.append((int(landMark.x*width), int(landMark.y*height)))
                myHands.append(myHand)
        return myHands

width=1920
height=1080


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Just use cv2.waitkey(1)? Aren't you already using that? does it work?

Comment: Yo super sorry, I forgot to add the addtional script I use. It is edited now.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

GUI (`imshow`) only works as long as `waitKey`/`pollKey` run **continuously or frequently**.

When you `sleep()`, you choke the GUI (`imshow` window). It can't update, or handle any events.

If you need to "sleep", give `waitKey` a suitable integer argument in milliseconds.

Be aware that `waitKey` can return *before* the time is up, e.g. if all windows were closed or if a key was pressed.